# FXM Add External Site Throws "System.InvalidOperationException" Error

Tags: fxm

version: Sitecore 8.2 update 1.

I'm getting an error whilst adding an external site to FXM.
when i complete the settings and click Save, the page appears to save but doesn't refresh the page as it usually does.
looking at the chrome console, i get the following error:

> http://localhost/sitecore/api/ssc/domainmatcher/service?id=%id% 500
>   (Internal Server Error) - entityservice.js
>
> Uncaught Error: {"Message":"An error has
>   occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"There is no method 'Filter' on type
>   'Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.QueryableExtensions' that matches the
>   specified
>   arguments","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"
>   at System.Linq.EnumerableRewriter.FindMethod(Type type, String name,
>   ReadOnlyCollection`1 args, Type[] typeArgs, BindingFlags flags)\r\n

using a clean build works but this particular version just seems to throw that error everytime.
any ideas that could lead me to resolving local setup issues causing this error?

thanks

Comment: Compare versions of dlls: `Sitecore.FXM.Service.dll` and `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.dll` in the bin folder of your site and with clean Sitecore 8.2 update 1.

Comment: What do you mean by clean build? Was this issue resolved? I am curious

Comment: @chorpo a clean version meaning, a fresh install of sitecore.  i'm having these issues on an existing sitecore website.